# Javascript Regex to discard match in specific html tag and match others?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, match

I need to match words in HTML but need to skip a tag (with specific class) and its contents.
Example:

```
<p> There is my way <span class="abc"> way beyond someone </span></p>
```

I need to match only first `way` word. Till now i am using word boundary to select word. `/\b(way)\b/ig` but it fails in below scenario.

```
<p> There is nothing. <span class="abc"> Way beyond someone </span></p>
```

In this statement i don;t want to match anything because `way` is inside the `span.abc` element.

I have tried `^` operator  but doesn't seems to work. i.e. `/(\b)way(\b)^("abc">the)/ig`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.

Comment: @Barmar I know we should not use regular expression. But in some cases you have  limited choices when you deal with huge data you choose every possible way to slow down the queries. Querying DOM is too slow and am well aware of theories since years, Please help in this case, I am stuck for 4 hours.

Comment: @esqew that question is filled with theories. I have tired most of those examples. It shouldn't be that complex.

Answer (score 0):

I don't  know a way to do what you want to, but you could use one regex for all the matches, use another regex for the ones you want to discard, and then  use only the matches in one match and not the other.
In your example:

```
way
```

Matches all the times this word appears

```
<span.*?>(.|\n)*?way(.|\n)*?<\/span>
```

Matches all span elements.
Then you cant get all matches for first regex wich weren't matched by the second one.

Answer (score 0):

i tried it in another method....
it returns the matched string without the word "Way"....

```
var str="<p> There is nothing. <span class=\"abc\"> Way beyond someone 
</span></p>";
var x=str.split(" ")
//console.log(x);
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
    //console.log(x[i])
    if(x[i]!="Way")
{
    console.log(x[i])

}

}
```

hope it is helpful...

Comment: please read the question again. The presence of word inside that HTML should be skipped and NOT MATCHED. Your solution is just doing the opposite.

Comment: @RajanVerma-edited the answer ....hope this is what your are asked....

Comment: Please read the question once again .Your solution also select these elements `<p>` and `<span` , `</span>`.  I have mentioned that i need to SKIP a TAG (with specific class) and its CONTENTS.